# Can't retrieve selected value from dropdown in dialog using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dialog popup with a few fields in them. This dialog is retrieved from a php file.
I can get the val() from all of them but the  dropdowns.

Snippets:

**Call dialog:**

```
$('#createNote').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({  url: 'functions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"function": "createNoteDialog"},
            success: function(data){`enter code here`
               $('#dialog-form').html(data);
               $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');}
  });
});
```

Generate Form:

```
if ($func == "createNoteDialog" ){
  echo '<form class="cmxform"><fieldset>';

  echo '<li><label for="Category">Category</label><select id="inputCategory" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">';
  $r_categories = mysqli_query($global_dbh,'select category from pledges.patchCategories order by 1 asc');    
  $first_row = mysqli_fetch_row($r_categories);
  echo '<option value="' . $first_row[0] . '" selected>' .$first_row[0] . '</option>';
  while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_categories)) != false) echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">' .$row[0] . '</option>';
  echo '</select>';

  echo '<label for="Version">Version </label><select id="inputVersion" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">';
  $r_versions = mysqli_query($global_dbh,'select version from pledges.patchVersions order by 1 desc');   
  $first_row = mysqli_fetch_row($r_versions);
  echo '<option value="' . $first_row[0] . '" selected>' .$first_row[0] . '</option>';
  while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_versions)) != false) echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '">' .$row[0] . '</option>';
  echo '</select>';

  echo '<li><label for="DevNote">Dev Note </label><textarea id="inputDevNote" name="DevNote" cols=60 rows=7></textarea></li>';
  echo '<li><label for="BuildNote">Build Note </label><textarea id="inputBuildNote" name="BuildNote" cols=60 rows=7></textarea></li>';
  echo '<li><label for="Comment">Comment </label><textarea id="inputComment" name="Comment" cols=60 rows=6></textarea></li>';

  echo '</fieldset></form>';
}
```

Saving:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 700,
      width: 800,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create Note": function() {
          $.post(    "functions.php"
                 , { "function": "saveNote" , "version": $("#inputVersion").val(), "category": $('#inputCategory').val()  ,"devNote": $('#inputDevNote').val() ,"buildNote": $('#inputBuildNote').val() ,"comment": $('#inputComment').val()});
            patchNotesTable.fnDraw();   
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    });
```

For some reason the $('#inputCategory').val() and $('#inputVersion').val() are empty, while the text area's are fine.

Also tried adding an onChange function to alert changes to the dropdown ... it wouldn't fire.

The form seems to be generated correctly:

```
<li><label for="Category">Category</label><select id="inputCategory" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
```

Just can't figure out why it can't grab those values :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Create another 
`<div class="loop">...</div>` inside your dialog box.  And put your all your stuff inside "loop".

After that try to reload this division just after ajax, after the click

```
$('#createNote').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({ ...
           ...
          ...

   });
  $(".loop").load("functions.php .loop", {"function": "saveNote" , "version": $("#inputVersion").val(), "category": $('#inputCategory').val()  ,"devNote": $('#inputDevNote').val() ,"buildNote": $('#inputBuildNote').val() ,"comment": $('#inputComment').val()});

});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help .. they still come up empty.

Comment: Ok.. plz tel me the flow.. when u click on 'createNote' a dialog will appear. After that you are putting Select Dropdown things which holds dynamic values. And you are getting the Val() of the dropdowns and you are closing the dialog. Rite?

Comment: That's correct. But the val is always empty when i try to get it. Could it possibly be a timing issue? ... i do the .post and then the window close. I've noticed on several occasion that when i do a fnDraw() on a table that i updated the line before with a .post it often doesn't take the changes.

Comment: ok fine. It might be happening something like this. You have some piece of code. And you have put it inside dialog box, which is not dynamic. The things should be like, when u open a dialog box, your select should have dynamic values at the time of dialog creation..  Put isset() for the 'createNote' click.  And put some 'console.log' for the values which you are getting.... you can fix the bug by yourself.